# Angular CLI compiler error, but if change smth (and can revert back) all is compiling successfully

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular5

While I compiling my app for the first time with

```
ng serve
```

it retrieves such error:
[img error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWyMB.png)

But if I change some compiling file(it can be any file), when angular cli using wepback recompiling it - all is OK.

I think I lose my dependencies link.

If you need some additional information - feel free to ask.
What the problem? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps update angular cli to latest. I had a similar error and it solved my Problem:

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

If it doesn't work try to clean your Cache and install it again:

```
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: I have had another problem with that, but in some case It might help

thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in tsconfig file

The

```
"moduleResolution": "classic"
```

I change to

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

And now it's work!